# How to determine, which parser rule called a method?

Tags: java, antlr

I need to implement the following functionality: my grammar can accept two range of values, `Value1` and `Value2`. If I give an input: `'set value1 100'`, it should print `'Accepted'`.

This much is working fine. But I need to enhance the code such that:

1. I print a customized message whenever I give some value which is made up of anything other than numeric digits.
2. If the integer does not lie the specified range, I display a customized error message telling that the value is not fit for value1/value2 inside inbounds method. The problem is, how do I know who called inbounds?

My code is as follows:

```
grammar grammar1;

@parser::members {
  private boolean inbounds(Token t, int min, int max) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(t.getText());    
    if(n >= min && n <= max) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      System.out.println("Value does not lie in the specified range");
      return false;
    }
  }
}

expr       :  SET attribute EOF;

attribute  :  Value1 integer1 { System.out.println("Accepted"); }
           |  Value2 integer2 { System.out.println("Accepted"); }
           ;

integer1   :  Int { inbounds($Int,0,1000) }? ;
integer2   :  Int { inbounds($Int,0,10000) }? ;
Int        :  '0'..'9'+;

SET        :  'set';
Value1     :  'value';
Value2     :  'value2';
```

Comment: How do we write such a situation in ANTLR:
expr: (Accepted_Values) { Do_Something(); } |
      (for_all_other_values) { Print_Error_Message(); }

Answer (score 1):

Trivial answer for this special grammar: whenever max is equal to `1000`, `inbound` has been called through the `value` expression, otherwise the input was a `value2` expression.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for my second question: 'How do I know who called the method inbounds'

The following grammar is solving this problem:

```
grammar first1;

@parser::members {
private boolean inbounds(Token t, int min, int max, String methodName) {
int n = Integer.parseInt(t.getText());    
if(n >= min && n <= max) {
  return true;
}
else {
  System.out.println("The range for value accepted by " + methodName+" is "+min +"-" + max );
  return false;
    }
   }
}

expr       :  SET attribute EOF;

attribute  :  Value1 integer1["Value1"] { System.out.println("Accepted"); }
           |  Value2 integer2 ["Value2"] { System.out.println("Accepted"); }
           ;

integer1 [String methodName]   :  Int { inbounds($Int,0,1000,methodName) }? ;
integer2 [String methodName]  :  Int { inbounds($Int,0,10000,methodName) }? ;
Int        :  '0'..'9'+;

SET        :  'set';
Value1     :  'value';
Value2     :  'value2';
```